# Sierpinski carpet use a stack instead of recursion

Tags: java, recursion, stack

I have implemented a solution to solve the  [Sierpinski carpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet) problem using recursion. Now I want to use a stack instead of the recursive method to solve the  Sierpinski carpet. I am trying to translate my recursive method into the stack, but I am having trouble when I push the variables from my recursive method. This is the piece of code that I have to push and pop

 `drawGasket(x + i * sub, y + j * sub, sub);`

When you call drawGasket(0, 0, 729), you should see the following on your screen:

[image]

Recursive method:

```
   public void drawGasket(int x, int y, int side) {
    int sub = side / 3; 

    //Draw center square
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x + sub, y + sub, sub - 1, sub - 1));

    if(sub >= 3) {
        //Draw 8 surrounding squares
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                if (j!=1 || i != 1)
                    drawGasket(x + i * sub, y + j * sub, sub);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stack implementation:

```
    public void stack (int x, int y, int side ){
    GenericStack<Integer> s = new GenericStack<>();

    int sub = side /3;
    g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x + sub, y + sub, sub - 1, sub - 1));

    while (!s.isEmpty()){
        x=s.pop();
        if (sub >=3){
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){    
                    if (j!=1 || i != 1){
                        int operation = x+i*sub;
                        s.push(operation);
                        int operation2 = y+j*sub;
                        s.push(operation2);
                        s.push(sub);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Stack Class:

```
public class GenericStack<T> {

private int size; // size
private Node<T> head; // node head

public GenericStack() { // constructor
    head = null; // head is null
    size = 0; // size is zero
}

public void push(T element) {
    if(head == null) { // if head is null
        head = new Node(element); // head is node 
    } else {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node(element);
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }

    size++;
}

public T pop() {
    if(head == null)
        return null;
    else {
        T topData = head.data;

        head = head.next;
        size--;

        return topData;
    }
}

public T top() {
    if(head != null)
        return head.data;
    else
        return null;
}

public int size() {
    return size;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

private class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private Node<T> next;

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a question.

Comment: The question (as I understand what is written) is "How do I write an iterative (stack-based) version of the recursive solution I already wrote?"

Answer (score 0):

If you can picture the recursive version as already being stack-based, you should be able to translate your code appropriately.  If you think of every recursive call to `drawGasket(x + i * sub, y + j * sub, sub);` as pushing three values onto a stack, and every first step "inside" the `drawGasket` method as popping three values off that stack, then explicitly pushing and popping those same values on and off your GenericStack in an iterative solution should follow the same pattern.  Basically, just as in the recursive solution, you need to push, push, push successive values onto the stack until you run out of values to push; and then you need to pop, pop, pop successive values off the stack and "draw" a rectangle appropriate to the values just popped until the stack is empty.

Comment: So when I pop the method do I do it at the beginning of the while loop, and for the recursion parameters do I push them one by one?

Comment: I think you're going to need two while loops, one for pushing and one for popping. `while(there are still items to push onto the stack)` and `while(there are still items to pop off of the stack)`.  Yes, you need to push the items one by one in the correct order, and then pop them off one by one in "reverse order".